# Subreport not printing after changing record selection

Tags: crystal-reports

My main report has 28 subreports. On subreport fails to print because of a parameter. We are only use `datedeb`, `datefin` and `site`, but this particular subreport needs a `sort order` which we don't use. Previously the record selection used this code:

```
if {?SortOrderParam} = 1
then {PINVOICE.NUM_0}
else {PINVOICE.BPR_0}
;
```

We changed the above code to:

```
if 1=1
then {PINVOICE.NUM_0}
else {PINVOICE.BPR_0}
;
```

Since we made this change it doesn't print headers or data. How can we resolve this?

Comment: You can simplify the second code snippet to just `{PINVOICE.NUM_0}`. No need for `if`, `else`, `then`, or `1=1`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this unfortunately only added one extra header, i'm still not getting any other headers or data

Comment: Have you tried switching to the other option? If you weren't ever passing in a value, the first formula would default to `{PINVOICE.BPR_0}`.

Comment: if you use `{PINVOICE.BPR_0}` then are you able to see the data and headers?

Comment: sadly no, it only brings up 1 additional header, basically if you pressed 1, then it would should everything for {PINVOICE.NUM_0} and if you pressed 2 then it would show everything for {PINVOICE.BPR_0} so i'm not sure if there is something else i'm missing.